# Symfony Phpunit 6.5, mock static function with will return result value

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have code where calling static function from class `File` and I want mock whit function and will add in `willReturn` some value, I need `File` object
I researched and understand - `staticExpects` from previous versions was deprecated. And my question what alternative without refactoring code for test coverage ?

My function from code

```
public function uploadSingle(array $params, UploadedFile $uploadedFile, FileHolderInterface $owner): File
{
    $file = File::create($filename, $target);
    //another logic

    return $file;
}
```

and my test

```
public function testUploadSingleUnit()
{
    $service = $this->createService();
    // some prepare data
    $result = $service->uploadSingle($params, $uploadedFile, $location);
}
```

I want `File` object in result variable for different compares

Comment: You could wrap File::create() in another (non-static) public function that then would act as a proxy to it so it's easy for you to mock. As one of the jobs of that class is to actually create these file objects it would also seem fair to make this more visible (by the public method). For more internal handling, inject a factory and then use that factory to create the file. This is more refactoring work but allows you to hide the internals in a testable (and maintainable) fashion. The public proxy method suggestion is perhaps some compromise you might prefer in this instant.

Comment: Is **File** the subject you want to put under test? (I don't think so, just asking for clarification)

Comment: @hakre that possible, changing logic, move to some public function where call static function and return result. But I want research answers, maybe it's possible without refactoring code.  I want to mock static function like it was in old version with help `staticExpects`.
  If it possible I will add tests for File object, but this is not main test functional.

Comment: You're basically looking for a way to patch work on that `File` identifier which is hardencoded. That is also the design flaw of that code and the unit testing does reveal that, so consider this the result (and a good one). If you for whatever reason (you can read any adjectives out of that as you like) need to actually bind reality of that code, well, change reality: http://patchwork2.org